# Android & Retrofit2 - posting image file in multipart request

Tags: android, image-uploading, retrofit2

I'm making an app in which I have to send image from gallery to server.

These should be headers (according to apiary).

```
Content-Type:image/jpeg
X-Filename:photo.jpg
```

But in logs in interceptor, there is only X-Filename, even though I tried multiple  ways and I'm running out of ideas.

Server responds with 200 but the next call (commit image) returns 500 with error at the end of post.

These are the methods:

```
    @Multipart
    @POST("uploads")
    Observable<String> uploadImage(
        @Header("Content-Type") String contentType,
        @Header("X-Filename") String fileName,
        @Header("Authorization") String token,
        @Part MultipartBody.Part file
    );

    @GET("uploads/{fileId}/commit")
    Observable<String> commitFile(
        @Header("Content-Type") String type,
        @Header("Authorization") String token,
        @Path("fileId") String fileId
    );
```

OkHttp client:

```
  private OkHttpClient createApiClient(Context context) {
      int cacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 MiB
      Cache cache = new Cache(context.getCacheDir(), cacheSize);

      OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
      builder.addInterceptor(chain -> {
          Request request = chain.request().newBuilder().build();
          request.newBuilder().addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
          Timber.d("Request: [%s] %s", request.method(), request.url());
          Timber.d("Request: %s", request.headers().toString());
          if (request.body() != null) {
              Timber.d("Request: %s", request.body().toString());
          }
          return chain.proceed(request);
      });
      builder.cache(cache);
      return builder.build();
  }
```

Resulting logs:

```
D/NetModule: Request: [POST] https://winged-guild-133523.appspot.com/api/v1/uploads
D/NetModule: Request: X-Filename: asura.png
                      Authorization: HAYVi3clcqjug53IPS6AYMgzCPGnDE3Si
D/NetModule: Request: retrofit2.RequestBuilder$ContentTypeOverridingRequestBody@7c37f46
```

Same thing happens with Postman - [Postman screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VcYm.png)

Commit fails with this error: (sorry for ugly formatting)

```
    {
        "errorCode": "ImagesServiceFailureException",
        "errorParam": "",
        "errorMessage":"com.google.appengine.api.images.ImagesServiceFailureException: "
}
```

As I said I'm running out of ideas and would greatly appreciate any help with this upload problem.

**(edit) PS:** by omitting *@Header("Content-Type") String contentType* in app and using *application/x-www-form-urlencoded* in Postman, image upload and commit are both successful, but Image at returned url has no metadata and therefore can't be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my code using retrofit

```
@Multipart
    @POST(ServiceConfig.API_CREATE_DEPENDENT_ACCOUNT)
    @Headers({
            "Accept: application/json",
            "Accept-Encoding: gzip"
    })
    Call<DataResponse<CreateDependentAccountResponse>>  createDependentAccount(@Query(JioConstants.ParamQuery.TOKEN) String token,
                                                                              @Query(JioConstants.ParamQuery.USER_ID) long userID,
                                                                              @Query(JioConstants.ParamQuery.FIRST_NAME) String firstName,
                                                                              @Query(JioConstants.ParamQuery.LAST_NAME) String lastName,
                                                                              @Query(JioConstants.ParamQuery.GENDER) String gender,
                                                                              @Query(JioConstants.ParamQuery.DOB) String dob,
                                                                              @Query(JioConstants.ParamQuery.RELATIONSHIP_ID) long relationshipID,
                                                                              @Query(JioConstants.ParamQuery.DISPLAY_UNIT) String displayUnit,
                                                                              @Part("avatar\"; filename=\"picture.jpg\" ") RequestBody file);
```

and

```
RequestBody file = null;
        if (mFileTemp != null) {
            file = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), mFileTemp);
        } else {
            file = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), "");
        }

        manageCall(ServiceManager.INSTANCE2().
                createDependentAccount(token, userID, firstName, lastName, gender, dob, relationshipID, displayUnit, file))
                .enqueue(new SimplifiedCallback<CreateDependentAccountResponse>() {

                    @Override
                    public void success(CreateDependentAccountResponse data, String message) {
                        hideLoading();
```

### Good luck. [This is my game](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thinhstudios.footballquiz)

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `@Multipart`. Instead, use something like this:

```
 @POST("upload/image")   
 Observable<ResponseBody> uploadImage(@Body RequestBody body);

 File imageFile = new File(path);   
 RequestBody body =  RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"),imageFile);

 api.uploadImage(body);
```

Comment: Thank you. What made the difference for me was being able to specify the file type by changing `"image/*"` to `"image/jpeg"`.